# CGI script presenting me "garbage" as opposed to JSON object

Tags: json, centos, cgi, port

So, for my testing environment here I have a Windows 8 machine running VMWare with a CentOS5 instance. I have two sites running. One of them can be reached at an IP address with port 1841, and the other with the default port. When trying to get JSON data from the default site FROM the 1841 site, I was obviously met with a cross browser issue. Even though the IP addresses are the same, I couldn't use the different ports.

OK, so the next thing I thought of would be to put a link from a folder in the default directory, and have it present the same information, and you know what? It worked! ***Sort of worked, actually.***

If I run from the terminal in the CentOS box, everything looks great.
[image: Here is the example of what I want]

Yet, when running from the browser, I get this...
[image: No such luck here]

What am I doing wrong here? To the browser, I now have the script appearing to be from the same root and port.

Comment: You need to post the command line you are using and the URL that you used in the browser. If both methods are getting from port 1841, then your problem is with the http GET and it's arguments or your URL.   Are you using `wget` or something like that on the command line?

Comment: I recommend getting rid of the JSON tag and port tag, as this has nothing at all to do with JSON or the concept of a port. This is a cgi configuration issue with your server and/or http GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you use Apache as a web server and got a MIME configuration problem since you get an executable (e.g. the elf header) which probably is the cgi script.

My recommendation is that you read Apache [cgi docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/cgi.html) and [mod_mime_magic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime_magic.html) in order to configure MIME properly.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, very close. I found that I wasn't working in Apache when trying to get the JSON. Moving my code to an Apache server that had the correct MIME configuration fixed the problem.

Comment: Ok, nice that my answer could help you to solve/figure out the problem 

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was, apparently placed on  a simple HTTP file server based on [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/). Which was fine for what Ext JS6 can do on its own, but when trying to incorporate this JSON object it wasn't entirely happy. Thank you once again.